# SQL query in php function 500 server error

Tags: php, pdo

I ran into a very strange thing.

This throws an 500 server error:

```
function writeMsg() {

 $id='0000000625';
 $translation = 'word';
 try {
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET HUN=? WHERE ID=?");
   $stmt->execute(array($translation,$id));
   $response["success"] = 1;
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
   $response["success"] = 0;
  }
  echo 'RESPONSE: '.$response["success"];

}
writeMsg();
```

This runs fine:

```
 $id='0000000625';
 $translation = 'word';
 try {
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET HUN=? WHERE ID=?");
   $stmt->execute(array($translation,$id));
   $response["success"] = 1;
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
   $response["success"] = 0;
  }
  echo 'RESPONSE: '.$response["success"];
```

I only removed the first and the last 2 lines.
Does anyone has an explanation to this?

Comment: Please show us where `$conn` is defined

Comment: yeah might need a - global $conn;

Comment: just add `global $conn;` inside your function

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a $conn thing. I'll be right back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably missed the `$conn` variable scope

```
 function writeMsg() {

     global $conn;

     $id = '0000000625';
     $translation = 'word';

     try {

         $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET HUN=? WHERE ID=?");
         $stmt->execute(array($translation, $id));
         $response["success"] = 1;

     } catch(\PDOException $e) {
         echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
         $response["success"] = 0;
     }

     echo 'RESPONSE: ' . $response["success"];

}

writeMsg();
```

Just use `global $conn` to retrieve the `$conn` variable from the global scope. Check more at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for **global** keyword

Comment: I didn't know about this. Thanks!